# Not being able to preload has_many through associated data

Tags: elixir, ecto

My association are:

```
defmodule Mp.Schema.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "users" do
    # ...
    has_many :user_gyms, UserGym, on_replace: :delete
    has_many :gyms, through: [:user_gyms, :gyms]
  end
end

defmodule Mp.Schema.UserGym do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "user_gyms" do
    # ...
    belongs_to(:user, User)
    belongs_to(:gym, Gym)
  end
end

defmodule Mp.Schema.Gym do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "gyms" do
    # ...
    has_many :user_gyms, UserGym, on_replace: :delete
    has_many :users, through: [:user_gyms, :users]
  end
end
```

I am trying to preload gyms:

```
query = from U in Mp.Schema.User, preload: :gyms
Mp.Repo.all(query)
```

But i am getting this error:

> schema Mp.Schema.UserGym does not have association or embed :gyms

There seems to have issue on association but I think I have fulfilled all requirements. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is failing for you is that you're using `:gyms` and `:users` in the `:through` lists. Those keys should refer to the associations on `UserGym`, which are `:user` and `:gym`, so, your code should look like:

```rb
defmodule Mp.Schema.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "users" do
    # ...
    has_many :user_gyms, UserGym, on_replace: :delete
    has_many :gyms, through: [:user_gyms, :gym]
  end
end
...
defmodule Mp.Schema.Gym do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "gyms" do
    # ...
    has_many :user_gyms, UserGym, on_replace: :delete
    has_many :users, through: [:user_gyms, :user]
  end
end
```

So, for instance `:gyms` is created as an association through the existing `:user_gyms` of the current schema and `:gym` on that schema.

If you look at the documentation for [`has_many/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3), you'll see there's an example using `through` and it has a comment that says:

```
# In the has_many :through example below, the `:comments`
# in the list [:comments, :author] refers to the
# `has_many :comments` in the Post own schema and the
# `:author` refers to the `belongs_to :author` of the
# Comment's schema (the module below).
```